# Can Collection_Select Be Used to Generate the Same Drop-Down List from a Reference Model for Multiple Variables in the Same Form?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, collections, migration, reference

I think my first version of this question was too complicated and demonstrated an incorrect attempt at solving the problem.  Consider the model in this hypothetical migration file:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.references :oem1
      t.references :oem2
      t.references :oem3

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :projects
  end
end
```

It is necessary for this program to:

1. Allow the user to assign values to oem1, oem2 and oem3 from a drop-down list of manufacturers.
2. Allow an Admin or Power User to add or remove values to the list from which the user(s) will select.

The second objective is easily achieved by creating a model like the one shown in this migration file:

```
class CreateOems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :oems do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :projects
  end
end
```

If I didn't have three unique OEM variables in the PROJECTs model I would just make **PROJECT :belongs_to oems** and **OEM :has_many projects** and just use **collection_select** to select an OEM name from the OEMs model and assign it to an OEM reference variable in the PROJECTs model.  However, I have three OEM variables and they cannot all be named OEM.  So, as far as I know, I cannot link all three of these variables to the OEM.name variable in a collection_select drop-down list.

So, what do I do?  Is there another way to accomplish those two objectives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you can do the following:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :oem1 %>
    <%= f.collection_select :oem1, Oem.all, :name, :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :oem2 %>
    <%= f.collection_select :oem2, Oem.all, :name, :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :oem3 %>
    <%= f.collection_select :oem3, Oem.all, :name, :name %>
  </p>

  <!-- The rest of your form... -->
<% end -%>
```

Not sure about your requirements, but it sounds like the relationship between projects and oems is many-to-many. So, how about using [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association)?

Comment: My error goes away if I change :oem1 to :oem1_id, Oem.all, ... etc, in the collection_select statement.  However, when I submit the form the show/index views display the ID from the OEM table - not the name.  If I leave it the way this your answer shows, I get the error:
`undefined method 'oem1' for #<Project:0x59e8a38>`
I remain stumped.  Any further suggestions would be appreciated.  
Thanks

Comment: Ultimately, I went with this solution (after removing the 's' from Oems.all to make it Oem.all.  At first I attempted to use ...,:id, :name) but I could never get the **undefined method** error to go away.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may be misunderstanding you, but are you saying this won't work?

```
- oems = Oem.all

= collection_select(:project, :oem1, oems, :id, :name, :prompt => true)
...
= collection_select(:project, :oem2, oems, :id, :name, :prompt => true)
...
= collection_select(:project, :oem3, oems, :id, :name, :prompt => true)
```

Comment: Yes, my thoughts exactly. Although `oem1`, `oem2` and `oem3` are strings in his migration, so I think he wants to save the name of the oem, not the id.

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for.  Do I need to change oem1, oem2 and oem3 to t.references?  Or can they stay as strings?

Comment: It depends on what you need, but you probably want it them to be integer ids (t.references).  Because then you can edit the names in the future.  The only reason you'd want them to be strings, really, would be if you didn't want to maintain the reference, but rather just write the name to the field once.

Comment: Then it's t.references I want.  I'll update the question.  Which :name gets changed to :id?

Comment: The first one.  Editing it back :-)